# New harddrive on a macbook pro 13 inch, dvd drive doesn't work, what do?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, install

What I don't have:

- An USB dvd drive

What I have:

- Another working, up to date, Macbook (with snow leopard).
- purchased Mountain Lion on the app store
- A desktop PC
- A 4GB usb stick.
- A USB harddrive I'd like not to wipe out entirely.

My macbook pro's dvd drive seems busted, I spray some dry air inside and tried to 90 degrees trick, did not work.

Doesn't apple provide some way to make a bootable usb thing ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the dvd drive with one of [these] lens cleaners CD's? They only cost a few dollar and it worked for me when I my superdrive didn't read any discs anymore.

Comment: Does your DVD drive have ANY working function? (for example, upon boot, the mechanism can be heard as it attempts to pull in any possibly available disk)

Comment: it does a sound when I turn the macbook on

Answer (score 1):

There is a few way you can do this from the working MacBook. The first is to follow the tutorial [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/how-to-create-a-bootable-backup-mountain-lion-install-disk/) which will take you through the process of making a bootable USB disk for Mountain Lion.

The steps involve

- Reformat the USB stick to HFS+
- Extract the install image from the downloaded installer
- Write the image to the USB using Disk Utility

Alternatively just download the [Lion DiskMaker](http://liondiskmaker.com/) software which will do all the work for you.

The only problem I can forsee is that you need an 8GB USB stick for this to work since the OSX installation is bigger then 4GB.

Comment: I wonder if I can resize my usb hdd partition, to not lose what's on it... ?

Comment: @jokoon Both method require the Drive to be reformatted a raw write to be done using `dd`. There is a very good change you will lose data.